# How to auto scale up/down Flink Stateful Functions on K8s

Tags: apache-flink, knative-serving, flink-statefun

## My Current Flink Application

- based on Flink Stateful Function 3.1.1, it reads message from Kafka, process the message and then sink to Kafka Egress
- Application has been deployed on K8s following guide and is running well: [Stateful Functions Deployment](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.2/docs/deployment/overview/)
- Based on the standard deployment, I have turned on [kubernetes HA](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/ha/kubernetes_ha/)

## My Objectives

I want to auto scale up/down the stateful functions.
I also want to know how to create more standby job managers

## My Observations about the HA

I tried to set `kubernetes.jobmanager.replicas` in the `flink-config` ConfigMap:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: flink-config
  labels:
    app: shadow-fn
data:
  flink-conf.yaml: |+
    kubernetes.jobmanager.replicas: 7
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
```

I see no standby job managers in K8s.

Then I directly adjust the replicas of deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: statefun-master
spec:
  replicas: 7
```

Standby job managers show up. I check the pod log, the leader election is done successfully. However, when I access UI in the web browser, it says:

```
{"errors":["Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh."]}
```

What's wrong with my approach?

## My Questions about the scaling

[Reactive Mode](https://flink.apache.org/2021/05/06/reactive-mode.html) is exactly what I need. I tried but failed, job manager has error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: Reactive mode is configured for an unsupported cluster type. At the moment, reactive mode is only supported by standalone application clusters (bin/standalone-job.sh).
```

It seems that stateful function auto scaling shouldn't be done in this way.
What's the correct way to do the auto scaling, then?

## Potential Approach(Probably incorrect)

After some research, my current direction is:

1. Job Manger has nothing to do with auto scaling. It is related to HA on K8s. I just need to make sure Job Manager has correct failover behaviors
2. My stateful functions are `Flink remote services`, i.e., they are regular `k8s services`. they can be deployed in form of `KNative service` to achieve auto scaling. Replicas of services goes up only when http requests come from Flink's worker
3. The most important part, Flink's worker(or Task Manager) I have no idea how to do the auto scaling yet. Maybe I should use `KNative` to deploy the Flink worker?
   If it doesn't work with KNative, maybe I should totally change the flink runtime deployment. E.g., to try the original [reactive demo](https://github.com/rmetzger/flink-reactive-mode-k8s-demo). But I'm afraid the Stateuful functions are not intended to work like that.

## At the last

I have read the Flink documentation and Github samples over and over but cannot find any more information to do this. Any hint/instructions/guideline are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since Reactive Mode is a new, experimental feature, not all features supported by the default scheduler are also available with Reactive Mode (and its adaptive scheduler). The Flink community is working on addressing these limitations.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/

Comment: I see reactive mode doesn't work for stateful functions. Is there any method to scale up stateful functions?